# getAmplitude isn't working

Tags: android, amplitude

When I try to work  it's show on textviev "0.0" value.
I get codes from this web site mostly
I get permissions to 
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`
ı give permission on setting-applications-mic
it's returned value "0.0"
how really works getAmplitude();
can some one explain

```
static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;
TextView text;
Button buton;
Handler handler;
boolean state = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_karpuz_sec);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    buton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    handler = new Handler();
    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!state){
                try {
                    start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
                stop();
        }
    });
}
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!state){
            text.setText(Double.toString(getAmplitudeEMA()));;
            handler.postDelayed(this,100);
        }
    }
};

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private double mEMA = 0.0;

public void start() throws IOException {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        mEMA = 0.0;
        state = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ses Ölçümü Başladı",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        buton.setText("DURDUR");
        text.setText(Double.toString(getAmplitudeEMA()));

    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
        state = false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ses Ölçümü Durdu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        buton.setText("BAŞLAT");
    }
}

public double getAmplitude() {
    if (mRecorder != null)
        return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
    else
        return 0;
}

public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
    double amp = getAmplitude();
    mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
    return mEMA;
}
```

}

Comment: I tried to fix your post, but it is still incomprehensible. Try [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), it may help.

Answer (score 0):

From [MediaRecorder documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude()), `getMaxAmplitude()` depicts :

> Returns the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last call to this method. Call this only after the setAudioSource().
>
> Returns : the maximum absolute amplitude measured since the last call, or 0 when called for the first time

This is why you get 0 the first time you call it in your `onCreate()`.

Request it on a regular basis if you want as this is what suggests the presence of your `Runnable`, here is an example scheduling your `getAmplitudeEMA()` every 500ms :

```
private Timer mTimer = new Timer();

.....

mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText(Double.toString(getAmplitudeEMA()));
            }
        });
    }

}, 0, 500);
```

And in `stop()` / `onPause()` :

```
mTimer.cancel();
mTimer.purge();
```